# How to escape backslashes from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, escaping, backslash

My input is a json containing windows file paths. I would like to display the file paths in html. Note that I cannot change the input string. Does anybody know what operation I can execute on my input string so that the backslashes would be displayed in my html page? I have been searching through many questions already, but I don't seem to find a solution for this problem.

```
// The json would be something like this.
data = [ 
  {"name": "Something", "link": "C:\something\something"},
  {"name": "Something Else", "link": "C:\something\something_else"}
  ];

// Loop over the json and add the elements to the html afterwards
var list = '';
$.each(data, function () {                    
    list += `
    <p> ${this.name} </p>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="${this.link}">
    `;
  });

$(".some-container").html(list);
```

When I use this code, no backslashes are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the backslashes by doubling them.

```js
// The json would be something like this.
data = [ 
  {"name": "Something", "link": "C:\\something\\something"},
  {"name": "Something Else", "link": "C:\\something\\something_else"}
  ];

// Loop over the json and add the elements to the html afterwards
var list = '';
$.each(data, function () {                    
    list += `
    <p> ${this.name} </p>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="${this.link}">
    `;
  });

$(".some-container").html(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-container"></div>
```

If you can't change the code, there's no solution. Escape sequences are replaced when parsing string literals, there's no way to recover the original source.

Escape sequences are only processed in string literals in source code. If you're getting the links from user input or an API, you don't have to worry about this at all.

Comment: In my post I say this: "Note that I cannot change the input string." I know that this is a possible solution, but I cannot change all the backslashes to double backslashes in the json by hand.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. The backslashes are removed when the code is parsed, there's no way to recover them. You need to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say a user inputs a string in an input field on a website. And said string contains a backslash. Will this backslash also be removed then?

Comment: No, this is only done to string literals in source code. Escape sequences aren't processed in input data.